# Typescript- filter: Provide multiple conditions in filter dyanmically

Tags: typescript2.0

I am bit curious if there is any way where i can have multiple conditions dynamically in the filter expression. For example

dataSource.filter(data => data.x === a && data.x === b && data.x === c)

it can have 'n' number of conditions, all will be dynamic only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not like that, no. You would have to pass in a function that accepts `data` or `data.x` and check against every possible condition.

```
function filterData(possibleValuesOfX: number[] = []) {
   return (data: Data) => {
      for (let value of possibleValuesOfX) {
         if (data.x === value) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
}

const filteredDataSource = dataSource.filter(filterData([a, b, c]));
```